# Creating Sharepoint 2013 List Items via Javascript from Apache webserver

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint

I have a website hosted on an Apache webserver with a custom html form. I also have a Sharepoint 2013 list (on the same network) that I need the custom html form to add an item to. So far I've been looking at the JSOM for SP (specifically sp.js and the like).

I've also looked at hosting the form on Sharepoint itself, with more success since it looks like sp.js is expecting a relative url, which doesn't make sense from the Apache server.

JS Code so far

```
 function save(){
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to submit this?")){
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(createListItem, "sp.js");
    }

}




function createListItem() {
    var siteUrl= "/sites/mysites/site";
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Sandbox');

    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
    oListItem.set_item('Title', 'My New Item!');
    oListItem.set_item('Line Type', 'Type 1');
    oListItem.set_item('Amount', '100');
    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.load(oListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    alert('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

HTML Header

```
<head>
    <script src="http://mysite/sites/site/_layouts/1033/init.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://mysite/sites/site/_layouts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://mysite/sites/site/_layouts/sp.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://mysite/sites/site/_layouts/sp.runtime.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://mysite/sites/site/_layouts/sp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="TER.js"></script>
    </head>
```

Note that in the Javascript I change the variable siteUrl as needed depending on which webhost I'm currently testing on (ie absolute or relative).

Does anyone know if what I'm trying to do is even possible or do I need to try a different approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use https://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/ or http://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/ to interact with Sharepoint lists and libraries using Javascript and AJAX.

Related to CORS, it is easier to host the custom HTML form directly on Sharepoint. I use this approach by hosting my HTML forms and JS files within a Sharepoint Document Library.

Using my favorite SharepointPlus, you can add a list item with:

```
$SP().list("ListName", "http://path/to/sharepoint/site/collection").add({ Title: "foobar" });
```

Kind regards

Comment: Hosting the html on Apache with an XmlHttpRequest to import the form to Sharepoint (had to allow CORS on the Apache server), along with SharepointPlus did the trick. Thanks.